# C# getting error while loading assembly with Assembly.LoadFrom(file.exe)

Tags: c#

I am trying to access methods list from the exe file   while trying to load assembly with

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(file.exe);
```

I am getting error attached below. I copied these from  locals section of debugging window .Hope someone can help  for this issue.

```
    DefinedTypes    Function evaluation timed out.  System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Reflection.TypeInfo>

    EntryPoint  Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. System.Reflection.MethodInfo

    EscapedCodeBase Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. string

    Evidence    Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. System.Security.Policy.Evidence

    ExportedTypes   Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Type>

    FullName    Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. string

    GlobalAssemblyCache Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. bool

    HostContext Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. long

    ImageRuntimeVersion Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation.
string

    IsDynamic   Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. bool

    IsFullyTrusted  Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. bool

    Location
Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. string

    ManifestModule  Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. System.Reflection.Module

    Modules Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Reflection.Module>

    PermissionSet   Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. System.Security.PermissionSet

    ReflectionOnly  Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. bool



    SecurityRuleSet Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation. System.Security.SecurityRuleSet
```

Comment: There is a limit on the amount of time that the debugger will spend evaluating an expression, and that time limit is pretty short.  It's not unusual for an expensive operation to time out.  I assume you are performing this command from the Immediate window.  What happens if you simply execute `asm` after the operation times out initially?

Comment: i copied these error messages from the debugger Local section using breakponint for asm. After executing this asm have some values but  i cant  use next line code which is Type type = asm.gettype() etc ıs not working

Answer (score 0):

Your probably missing some dependencies, but we can't be sure, since the exceptions you posted, pretty much give no information at all.

They say, you should have stepped your debugger to get the correct exception information.

Maybe you can try it again, and post some useful readable exceptions.

Comment: Actually, the error _is_ a message from the debugger. The root cause is something else, like a deadlock or an otherwise instable process.

Comment: Yes the debugger gives an error that it can not evaluate the properties of the Exception that was raised. But given the way the question is formulated, I thought it was about the Exception, not the debugger :)

Comment: Dont know how i can set the debugger to get more info about this issue